# The Underlying Provider Failed to open

Tags: c#

HI,

I am using VS2010 and working with Microsoft Entity Framework 4.0

I am working on a Windows Application. I have bound several combo in my application; it's working fine.

```
void BindNatureOfIndustryCombo()
{
    using (var obj = new EASDBEntitiesCon())
    {
        var natureOfIndustryColl = from c in obj.IndustryTypes select c;
        var natureOfIndustryList = natureOfIndustryColl.ToList();

        cmbNatureOfIndustry.DataSource = natureOfIndustryList;
        cmbNatureOfIndustry.DisplayMember = "IndustryType";
        cmbNatureOfIndustry.ValueMember = "IndustryTypeID";

    }
}
```

**ConnectionString is**

```
<add name="EntrpriseApplicationSuit.Properties.Settings.EASDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.150\GSERVER;Initial Catalog=EASDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=$1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But when I start my application on another system, it gives the error:

**The Underlying Provider Failed to open**

Why does this error occur and what is the solution?

Answer (score 6):

That suggests that the connection string is invalid from the other computer. Perhaps it's using Windows authentication and the other user or computer doesn't have permission to access it - or perhaps it's on a different network and can't reach the server? We can't really diagnose that without knowing a bit about what it's trying to connect to.

Please give as much context as you can around the connection, and any differences between the computer it *is* working on and the computer it's *not* working on.

Comment: HI jon i am using sql server authentication and userid password every thing is correct and when  i open my application on other system and  Update Model from database in my model then its started working fine

Comment: @Nagendra: I'm afraid it really isn't clear what you mean by "open my application on other system and update model from database in my model".

Answer (score 0):

You should double check your connection string!

To ensure that the database server/instance is correct, the database name is correct, the user id and (or) password you use are valid.

Comment: it is correct as i said when i am running this on my system the its working fine when i am running this application on any other system then it give error and every thing is correct ServerName , Id , Password , database name every thing is correct i have checked it very carefully

Comment: @Nagendra: Have you checked if you are actually able to connect to the specified SQL Server from the machine where your application fails?

Answer (score 0):

Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) might be disabled. Try enabling DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.

Open DTC by going to Component Services / Computers / My Computer / Distributed Transaction Coordinator / Right click Local DTC / Properties / Security Tab / Check Enable Network DTC Access / Allow Remote Clients.